# RAILS 6 - Select specific columns but don't lose foreign key informantion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have this model relation :

Task -> has many Groups

Group -> belongs to Task

Now I want get all Tasks like

```
tasks = Task.order(updated_at: :desc).select(:task_name, :task_status).last(10).reverse
tasks.each do |t|
  group = t.groups 
end
```

But this does not work because the foreign key information is lost when I do a select(...) statement in the first line.

Or I could do that :

```
tasks = Task.order(updated_at: :desc).last(10).reverse
tasks.each do |t|
  group = t.groups
  task_info = t.select(:task_name, :task_status)
end
```

But this does also not work. My target is to have the foreign key information AND to select just a few columns.

And idea ?

Comment: What is this foreign key information that you're mumbling about? Since the `task_id` column is on the groups table you would have to join that table. This just stinks of a X&Y question as your basically just doing what should be done with joins/left_joins, includes or eager_load in a way that creates a N+1 query issue. If you instead can show us an example of the data and what the actual desired output is we can show you how to actually solve the problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: If you want to know why this code does not work its because you are not selecting tasks.id. When you do `t.groups` Rails can't fetch it since `groups.task_id` references `tasks.id`. The end result is something like `SELECT * FROM groups WHERE tasks.id = NULL`.

Comment: But that still leaves the fact that you are doing n+1 or even n+2 queries which is should be a much bigger concern then if your doing `SELECT tasks.*` or just a few columns which is most likely just premature optimization.